# Guess the Number Game with Different Guess Names

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first time visiting using stackoverflow--I'm new to programming and am taking a beginner's course for Python. Excited to get started!

Our second assignment asks us to create the well-known Guess the Number Game. For those of you who already know this game, I would love some help on an extra piece that's been added to it: we must list off each guess with their respective order. A sample output should look like this:

- I'm thinking of an integer, you have three guesses.
- Guess 1: Please enter an integer between 1 and 10: 4
- Your guess is too small.
- Guess 2: Please enter an integer between 1 and 10: 8
- Your guess is too big.
- Guess 3: Please enter an integer between 1 and 10: 7
- Too bad. The number is: 5

I've got the coding down to where I have Guess 1 and Guess 3 appear, but I cannot make Guess 2 appear. I've been reworking and replacing every "while", "if", "elif", and "else" command to fix this, but can't seem to come up with a solution! Here is my code so far:

```
def guess():
print ("I'm thinking of an integer, you have three guesses.")
attempts = 0
from random import randint
number = randint(0,10)
guess = eval(input("Guess 1: Please enter an integer between 1 and 10: "))
while guess != number and attempts == 0:
    if guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too small.")
        break
    if guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too big.")
        break
    elif guess == number:
        print("You got it!")
        attempts = attempts + 1
if number != guess and attempts == 1:
    guess = eval(input("Guess 2: Please enter an integer between 1 and 10: "))
    if guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too small.")
    elif guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too big.")
    while guess == number:
        print("You got it!")
        attempts = attempts + 1
elif number != guess and attempts == 2:
    guess = eval(input("Guess 3: Please enter an integer between 1 and 10: "))
    if guess < number:
        print("Too bad. The number is: ", number)
    elif guess > number:
        print("Too bad. The number is: ", number)
    while guess == number:
        print("You got it!")
```

This code outputs Guess 1 and then quits. Can anyone help me figure out how to make Guess 2 and 3 appear?? All ideas are welcome--Thanks!

Comment: Just a side note, you do NOT want to use eval() for the input. If you run this as a web application, the user can directly manipulate the server. Instead, use a try & except and an int(input()) statement.

Comment: This program is not intended for web application, so, at the moment, I'm not worried about server manipulation. But thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the "concatenation" method along with some of your helpful response ideas and finally got my code to work!! Thank you all so, so much for the help!! Here is the correct code for this program:

```
def guess():
from random import randint
number = randint(0,10)
print("I'm thinking of an integer, you have three guesses.")
attempts = 0
while attempts < 2:
    guess = eval(input("Guess " + str(attempts + 1) + ": Please enter an integer between 1 and 10: "))
    if guess < number:
        print("Your guess is too small.")
        attempts += 1
    elif guess > number:
        print("Your guess is too big.")
        attempts += 1
    else:
        print("You got it!")
        break

else:
    attempts == 3
    guess = eval(input("Guess 3: Please enter an integer between 1 and 10: "))
    if guess < number:
        print("Too bad. The number is: ", number)
    elif guess > number:
        print("Too bad. The number is: ", number)
    else:
        print("You got it!")
```

And then ending it with a call to function ("guess()"). Hope this serves well for those who experience this problem in the future. Again, thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten you code quite a bit, just move the input in the loop and keep looping for either three attempts using range or the user guesses correctly:

```
def guess():
    print ("I'm thinking of an integer, you have three guesses.")
    from random import randint
    number = randint(0,10)
    # loop three times to give at most three attempts
    for attempt in range(3):
        # cast to int, don't use eval
        guess = int(input("Guess 1: Please enter an integer between 1 and 10: "))
        if guess < number:
            print("Your guess is too small.")
        elif guess > number:
            print("Your guess is too big.")          
        else: # not higher or lower so must be the number  
            print("You got it!")
            break
```

It  would be better to use a while with a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to verify the user inputs a number, looping until the user has used 3 attempts or guesses correctly:

```
def guess():
    print ("I'm thinking of an integer, you have three guesses.")
    attempts = 0
    from random import randint
    number = randint(0,10)

    while attempts < 3:
        try:
            guess =int(input("Guess 1: Please enter an integer between 1 and 10: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("That is not a number")
            continue
        if guess < number:
            print("Your guess is too small.")
            attempts += 1
        elif guess > number:
            print("Your guess is too big.")
            attempts += 1
        else: # if it is a number and not too high or low it must be correct
            print("You got it!")
            break # break the loop
```

You cannot just use an `if/else`  if you actually want to give the user feedback on whether their guess was too low or too high.

Also as commented **don't** use eval. Some good reason why are outlined [here](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: Thank you for the tips! Your comment really helped. On a sidenote, our professor has taught us only a few commands, eval being one of them. I suppose she expects us to use eval for the first few coding assignments to understand the whole concept of evaluating inputs... But I'll make a note of this for future codes.

Comment: No prob, it is strange that the professor is using eval it is very rarely used especially when taking user input.

Answer (score 0):

1. All your `while guess!=number and attempts ==` loops are useless, because you're either `break`ing out of them or incrementing `attempts` so their condition evaluates to `False` after the first iteration.
2. Guess 2 is never reached because either `number` equals `guess` (so `number != guess` is `False`) or `attempts` is still zero.
3. Guess 3 is never reached for the same reason. However, **if** guess 2 would be reached, guess 3 would **never** be reached because you put `elif` in front.

Try to get rid of the code for guess 2 and guess 3. Write all the code for `guess = eval(input())` and `if guess < number: ... elif guess > number: ...` **once** and put it inside a loop. Here's a bit of pseudocode to illustrate the idea:

```
while attempts < 3
    ask for user input
    if guess equals number
        print "you win"
        exit the loop
    else
        print "that's wrong"
```